# Closure of thread c#.net

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services

I have developed a multi-threaded  application which start threads inside a loop.

Do i need to worry about closure/terminate of the thread or it will close automatically.

i am creating new threads in every sec and it is running continuously as below.

Run() method is calling by windows service.

```
public void Run(int count) 
{
       for(i=count i<count ;i++)
       {
          ThreadTest  t=new ThreadTest();
          Thread newThread = new Thread(t.DoWork);
          newThread.Start();
       } 
}

 Class ThreadTest 
 {

   Public void DoWork() 
  {
     // do some calculation and update database fields. 
  }

 }
```

Comment: Just a comment: Starting threads like this is typically a bad idea as you're paying significant overhead with each new thread. If possible use the thread pool to amortize the cost of thread management.

Comment: I recommend using the ThreadPool.  Manual threads have considerable overhead as Brian mentioned.  Including a 1MB stack that gets allocated every time.  The thread pool will pool the unused threads and reuse them without reallocating them whenever you need a new one.

Comment: @BradleyUffner but to run on thread pool thread i need to use ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem and it will not start thread immediately may be there is a 1/2 sec delay. i need to start thread as ASAP.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen  once the thread completes the method/job , isn't it deallocate the memory used.

Comment: @FatalError As everyone else said, allocating a `Thread` has substantial overhead and you may end up exahusting systen resources. The `Thread` class has no guarantee of thread creation and execution time,  what does immediately mean to you?

Comment: Yes, the memory will deallocated when the thread exits.  I don't know how many threads you are spinning up every second, but keep in mind that EACH thread is going to allocate and then deallocate at least 1mb of ram EVERY second.  That is a LOT of overhead.  If the built in thread pool doesn't do what you need you may be able to create your own thread pooling that is more responsive.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Please give me an clue advice/link to create own thread pooling. thanks

Comment: Here is one example I found Googling for `C# Custom Thread Pool`. http://smartthreadpool.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A thread terminates when the function that you specify returns. If you manage to create threads faster than they finish you'll accumulate running threads and eventually exhaust the resources of your system. Is it really necessary to have an unbounded amount of threads?